# How do I manually put cookies in a jar?

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, cookielib

I'm using python with urllib2 & cookielib and such to open a url. This url set's one cookie in it's header and two more in the page with some javascript. It then redirects to a different page.

I can parse out all the relevant info for the cookies being set with the javascript, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get them into the cookie-jar as cookies.

Essentially, when I follow to the site being redirected too, those two cookies have to be accessible by that site.

To be very specific, I'm trying to login in to gomtv.net by using their "login in with a Twitter account" feature in python.

Anyone?

Comment: soo... Who stole the cookies from the cookie-jar?

Comment: @DampeS8N stole the cookies from the cookie jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set cookies for another domain - browsers will not allow it.

Comment: Well, in this instance I am the browser. E.g. I'm doing client side scripting so I can just do whatever with the cookie-files on disk and such...